# eclipse plugin for static call graph

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I am actually looking for an eclipse plugin which can generate a static call graph for a java project. Could anyone suggest me any such plugins?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you ask for, but you can select any method in Java and invoke Navigate -> Open Call Hierarchy... That will give you a new view with the call tree for the current method. Pretty cool in my book...